# Changing the background color of my React app based on if another component is in the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

just looking for some advise on a best possible starting place for the described issue.

I'm using React and StyledComponents and basically want to ensure that if a certain component is present in the DOM (navigation bar) - that the background colour is white and if it isn't present, then we make the background-color grey.

The background color is being set here like so:

```
const StyledMain = styled(Main)`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 100vh;

  input:-webkit-autofill,
  input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
  input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
  input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: ${themeProp("BODY_COLOR")};
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
`;
```

Is it possible to do this check with styled components and render a different background-color based what components may be rendered in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props to styled components as they themselves are React components. So you can use the same prop which determines whether to show/hide the navigation bar to determine the background color of the component. Sample styled component code will be something like this:

```
background-color: ${props => props.showNavbar ? "white" : "grey"};
```

and you'll pass the prop when you use the component

```
<StyledMain showNavbar={someValueDetermineNavbarStatus}></StyledMain >
```